# how do I avoid the error of actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

How do I correct the error of 
"actual and formal argument lists differ in length"

the constructor class is properly setup, still it shows this error which shown at "notebookref.add...."

```
private void saveNote() {
        String title = editTextTitle.getText().toString();
        String description = editTextDescription.getText().toString();
        int priority = numberPickerPriority.getValue();

        if (title.trim().isEmpty() || description.trim().isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please insert a title and description", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        CollectionReference notebookRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("Notebook");
        notebookRef.add(new ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note(title, description, priority));
        Toast.makeText(this, "Note added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }

this is the error message being shown
"actual and formal argument lists differ in length"
```

arguments

```
public class Note {
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private int priority;

    public Note() {
        //empty constructor needed
    }

    public Note(String title, String description, int priority) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public int getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide the correct number of arguments.

Comment: arguments added

Comment: Is this a nested class? If so, you almost certainly meant it to be a `static class`.

Comment: no it is not the nested class

Comment: Why are you calling in this way `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note` if you say it is not a nested class? Please also responde with @AlexMamo